# How can a neural network developed using TensorFlow remember old memories?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, training-data, recurrent-neural-network

I'm new to TensorFlow and NN. I developed a tensor model which says the sentiment of text using LSTM's. My model trains until given number of epochs or iterations and saves the model for a certain number. (I.e., I save model after every 5 epochs.) Once training is done I pick up the last checkpoint file and use it for prediction.

but my doubt comes when I ran my training code once again with new data. I'm getting confused.

Does the past data memories are with newly created checkpoint files or not. For Example, when I trained my model with `epoch=150`, I got `./models/tensorflow/model-150`. Now again I have restored the model-150 and started training with new data now because of saving logic step

```
saver.save(sess, os.path.join(model_path, 'model'), global_step=epoch)
```

I'm not seeing model-151 instead of that old model-1 is replaced with new mode-1. Here what I want to know is whether the first model-150 memories exist with second time trained and created model-150 are not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you still have the effect of the 150 first epochs in your network, it's just that the new file is saved with the epoch number that you're providing in global_step, it wwon't go look in the network if it's already trained. I suggest you write  `saver.save(sess, os.path.join(model_path, 'model'), global_step=epoch+150)` instead (or something cleverer that reads the previous number of epochs in the checkpoint name, and then adds it to your global_step)

Comment: I tried the logic looks like i got succeed but how can I make sure that new data is training on the last checkpoint file and creating the new check point file.

Comment: test with 1 epoch, then with 150 epochs, then with 150 epochs+1 epoch on new data. Do these tests on the same dataset, for instance from the first training set. You should see bad results for 1 epoch, and good ones for 150 and 150+1 epochs, which will prove to you that 150+1 did build on top of the 150 checkpoint.